Не получается получить данные с ManyToManyField выводит my_app.Location.None Django
Прошу помощи не могу получить данные. {{ s.location }} выводит my_app.Location.None
models.py
class Si(models.Model):
    name_si = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Наименование СИ")
    numb_man = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Заводской номер")
    numb_inv = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Инвентарный номер")
    location = models.ManyToManyField('Location', verbose_name="Место монтажа") #symmetrical=False,through='Moving', through_fields=('si_id','location_id')

class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Место установки")
    lon = models.FloatField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Долгота")
    lat = models.FloatField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Широта")

views.py
def metrolog(request):
    si = Si.objects.all()
    data = {"title": "Средства измерения", "si": si}
    return render(request, 'mnkt_app/metrolog.html', context=data)

index.html
{% for s in si %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ s.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ s.name_si }}</td>
       <td>{{ s.location }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

есть малое продвижение
index.html
{% for s in si %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ s.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ s.name_si }}</td>
       <td>{{ s.location.all }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

но данные выводятся не корректно <QuerySet [<Location: Объект#1>]>.
Вот как теперь заполучить только наименование место монтажа Объект#1

{{ s.location }} вы так обращаетесь к объекту класса Location.
Вам следует попробовать {{ s.location.location }}
Либо определить функцию в классе Location, что нужно возвращать при обращению к объекту класса Location. Например так
def __str__(self):
    return self.location


Нет так тоже не работает

Добавли  def str(self): return  self.location результата тоже нет

Вот так {{ location.1 }} выводит но мне надо перебрать все средства измерения и вывести данные где он смонтирован

index.html
{% for s in si %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ s.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ s.name_si }}</td>
       <td>{{ s.location.get }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

Вот и все получилось
